# Should I Use DAO Objects In Python __init__?

Tags: python, class, object, instance, dao

In python, which is better:

```
class MyAPI:

    def __init__(self):
       self.dao = MyDAO()

    def getsomething(self):
       something = self.dao.grabSomething()
       newsomething = operateon(something)
       return newsomething

    def getsomethingelse()
       somethingelse = self.dao.grabSomethingElse()
       newsomethingelse = operateon(somethingelse)
       return newsomethingelse
```

OR

```
class MyAPI:

    def getsomething(self):
       dao = MyDAO()
       something = dao.grabSomething()
       newsomething = operateon(something)
       return newsomething

    def getsomethingelse()
       dao = MyDAO()
       somethingelse = dao.grabSomethingElse()
       newsomethingelse = operateon(somethingelse)
       return newsomethingelse
```

I am a complete python noob coming from a java spring background and I am really trying to understand the difference here.

Comment: VTC as opinion-based, but IMHO: Neither of these, you should take `dao` as a parameter to `__init__()` instead.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, using constructor injection, but the problem with doing that in python is that eventually you may get code like the below which would just balloon, because you you don't have something like spring to manage the instances in a "clean" way:



ds = DataSource()
dao = MyDAO(ds)
api = MyAPI(dao)...etc

Comment: That's what freestanding functions are for.  Just write a `make_MyAPI()` function that creates all of those things with sensible defaults and/or reads things out of a config file to decide which class to initialize.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example of using a freestanding function in this manner and I will accept the answer?